# Looping through list of database to drop and recreate a view

Tags: database, t-sql, cursor, view

I am unsure if it is possible to do this with a loop in TSQL.

I have a list of Databases I would like to loop through and for each database drop and recreate the view as necessary.

I have a script already to drop and recreate the view. However, presently at the top of my script I have a bunch of use statements and i just go down the list uncommenting and reruning the script. However I would like to automate it so it would be much faster. I have done a similar thing in the past looping though a string of database names and using it to execute a use statement. Which works except when creating views because the view has to be seperated by go statements. Here is a code snippet of my code to parse databases any help to make work with views would be great.

```
DECLARE @DBs AS VARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @OneDB AS VARCHAR(255);
DECLARE @CmdToExec AS VARCHAR(MAX);

SET @DBs = 'db1,db2,db3,db4,db5,db6,db7,db8,db9,db10,db11,db12,db13,db14,db15,db16'

DECLARE DB_Cursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT SUBSTRING( ',' + @DBs + ',', n + 1,
        CHARINDEX( ',', ',' + @DBs + ',', n + 1 ) - n - 1 ) AS "dbInfo"
    FROM CommunityPAL.dbo.Numbers
    WHERE SUBSTRING( ',' + @DBs + ',', n, 1 ) = ','
        AND n < LEN( ',' + @DBs + ',' );
OPEN DB_Cursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM DB_Cursor INTO @OneDB;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @CmdToExec = 'USE ' + @OneDB;
    EXEC @CmdToExec;

    --statements to execute

    FETCH NEXT FROM DB_Cursor INTO @OneDB;
END
CLOSE DB_Cursor
DEALLOCATE DB_Cursor
```

Comment: "have a list of Databases I would like to loop through and for each database drop and recreate the view as necessary." - Why?

Comment: new fields need to be added to each of the views I have a web application that uses the views from the different client databases

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you can't do what you want exclusively within T-SQL. `CREATE VIEW` (and `ALTER VIEW`) do not use the three-part naming convention (database.schema.object). It has to be the only statement in a batch, so it cannot be combined with a `USE` command within a dynamic SQL call (`EXEC` or `sp_executeSQL`), and the effects of that `USE` will only last until the duration of that batch (i.e. until any embedded `GO`).

However, I have done similar work from “outside” SQL server, updating specific objects in all databases of a certain "type" (where we have one per client/customer). It gets complex. A brief outline:

- Use the scripting (or programming) language of your choice
- Loop over a list of databases
- Execute SQLCMD once for each database, and execute your `[RE]CREATE VIEW` script

Comment: Also persists for child scopes. `EXEC ('USE tempdb; EXEC(''CREATE VIEW foo AS SELECT 1 AS X'')')`

Comment: Ooh, nested dynamic SQL. Get thee behind me, Satan! (Though it probably would work...)

Answer (score 0):

Please check the `sp_msforeachdb` procedure to loop for the all databases:

[Take advantage of undocumented SQL Server iteration procedures](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/datacenter/take-advantage-of-undocumented-sql-server-iteration-procedures/395)

Comment: You still have the problem of "CREATE VIEW can be the only statement in the batch", which is relevant because he'll want code to determine if he wants to run it in *this* database (i.e. syntax like `IF ''?'' like [list of DBs]`